# What does the number indicate on Xcode top middle panel?

Tags: xcode7.1.1

I am running an app in `Xcode` . I used to press on stop button and hit run button frequently to test few things. However I notice that, everytime I hit the run button, a number is incremented in the top middle panel of xcode where it shows the building/running/indexing status of the project.When I click on it, it displays a list of running on iphone messages!!!

[image]

After some succesful run of 3 attempts, the simulator is slowed down, and the xcode simply shows the number incremented of how many times I hit the run button.But the app isnt loaded on the simulator,still xcode says that app is running on simulator.

How to make this number come to 0 ? The only way to make it zero is to quit the simulator completely and start it again. I dont want to quit the simulator.

Is there any other way?

Comment: It's the number of things Xcode is doing.  For example running apps, indexing source files, downloading and installing docs, etc.  In your particular case it looks like you aren't stopping the debug run somehow.

Comment: Is there a way to do a force stop ?

Comment: Not sure.  It shouldn't be getting confused like that...